# Find minimum difference between pairs of numbers chosen from array of ranges

Tags: algorithms, graphs, time-complexity, optimization, arrays

I recently thought of this problem, and I think it's very interesting. We are given an array of $N$ numbers, but we don't know the numbers themselves, only a possible integer range for each number. For instance, if $N = 3$, we could know that the first number is in the range $[1, 1000]$, the second number is in the range $[2, 100]$, and the third number is in the range $[5, 6]$. Now, the task is to find the minimum number $x$ such that no pair of numbers in the array has absolute difference greater than $x$. For the three ranges given above, $x$ clearly is 0 (we could choose the array to be $\{5, 5, 5\}$, for instance).

Obviously, we could brute-force this problem by  testing every possible combination. But I think we could also binary search on $x$. The problem is, I don't know how we would *test* the validity of a fixed $x$ efficiently (my best idea so far is to just test every range $[i, i + x]$ and see if we could assign every number in the array to that range).

I also think that perhaps there's a way to reduce this problem  to graph theory... perhaps with an implication graph. But this hasn't gotten me anywhere.

Does anyone have an idea/insight that could help solve this problem?

Comment: Your description of the problem is misleading. You want to choose one number from each range, minimizing the difference between the maximal choice and the minimal choice.

Comment: Try sorting all endpoints and scanning them in increasing order.